# If $r$ is irrational, there is a unique integer $n$ with $|r- n|<1/2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm working on proving the following statement:

**Show that if r is an irrational number, there is a unique integer n such that the distance between r and n is less than $\frac{1}{2}$.**

How do I show uniqueness using a proof by contradiction? How do I first establish that such a case even exists?

I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Suppose there were two integers $n,m$ with a distance to $r$ of less than $\frac12$. What would that imply about the distance between $m$ and $n$?

Comment: Uniqueness should be easy: If $r$ is at distance $a$ from $n$, what distance is it from $n+1$? From $n-1$? From $k>n+1$ or from $l<n-1$?

Comment: Existence should also be easy, depending on what you can assume: Do you know that there is an integer $k$ such that $k<r<k+1$?

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm not sure.

Comment: @Bob Actually the first question to ask you is: What is an irrational number?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen A number that can't be expressed as a fraction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For uniqueness.

Suppose there were two distinct integers $n$ and $m$ such that $|r - n| < 1/2$ and $|r - m| < 1/2$. Then $|n - m| \le |r - n| + |r - m| < 1/2 + 1/2 = 1$, i.e., $|n - m| < 1$. But as $n$ and $m$ are two distinct integers we have a contradiction since $|n - m| \ge 1$.

Comment: What does |n−m|≥1 contradict?

Comment: The contradiction is that these are supposed to be different integers and thus they are least 1 apart, yet the conclusion was |n-m|<1 since it is less than 1/2 away from r.

Comment: how can we get |n−m|≤this stuff

Comment: @MolyHoly $n - m = (n - r) + (r - m)$. Apply the triangle inequality. $|n - m| \le |n - r| + |r - m| = |r - n| + |r - m|$.

Answer (score 1):

For existence consider $\lfloor r+\dfrac12 \rfloor$. For uniqueness note that if $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ are two such numbers, then $|m-n| = \left|(m-r)+(r-n)\right| \le |m-r| + |n-r|$.