# How can we form the relation of inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

[If $r$ is irrational, there is a unique integer $n$ with $|r- n|<1/2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/537408/if-r-is-irrational-there-is-a-unique-integer-n-with-r-n1-2)

There are $$|n−m|\le |r−n|+|r−m|< \frac12 + \frac12 =1$$ in the answer, I understood all the steps except the relation of $|n−m|\le$ , how can we know $|n−m|\le|r−n|+|r−m|$

Our information:

- $|r−n|<1/2$
- $|r−m|<1/2$
- $|r−n|+|r−m|<1/2+1/2$

So how can we get $|n−m| \le |r−n|+|r−m|<1/2+1/2$

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Key step is a variant of triangle inequality $|a-b| \le |a| + |b|$. You have
$$
|n-m| = |(n-r) - (m-r)| \le |n-r| + |m-r| = |r-n|+|r-m|
$$